# Triple DES initialization vector

Tags: php, aes, des, tripledes

I have a working code to generate encrypt data using PHP:

```
$cipher_alg = MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES;
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher_alg,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND); 
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher_alg, $pKey, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

Question is, I run this code multiple time, if the same inputs and always give me the same output for `$encrypted_string` and a different output for `$iv`.
So why my encrypt data is always the same if the IV changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ECB mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) does not use an IV, so it doesn't matter what you pass in or that it's different every time. The documentation for [`mcrypt_encrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) itself indirectly says so:

> **`iv`**
>
> Used for the initialization in CBC, CFB, OFB modes, and in some algorithms in STREAM mode. If you do not supply an IV, while it is
>   needed for an algorithm, the function issues a warning and uses an IV
>   with all its bytes set to "\0".

You would need to use a chainable mode (CBC etc) to see different results on each iteration -- and in general, ECB mode is a very bad choice. Don't use it.